# Tikz circle diameter when letter inside?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, circles

I have the following tikz code:

```
\tikzstyle{city} = [draw, fill=white!20, circle, node distance=0.5cm]

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(current bounding box.center)},node distance=0.7cm]
\node [city] (S) {};
\node [coordinate,right of=city] (S1) {};
\node [city,above of=S1] (j1) {$j$};
\node [city,above of=j1] (i1) {};
\node [city,below of=S1] (k1) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Which produces the following output:

[image]

How do I make it so that the circle containing `j` is the same diameter as the other circles and doesn't blow up like that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `label={...}` instead of node text to make the node size independent of the text size.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{city} = [draw, fill=white!20, circle, node distance=0.5cm]

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(current bounding box.center)},node distance=0.7cm]
\node [city] (S) {};
\node [coordinate,right of=S] (S1) {};
\node [city,above of=S1, label=center:$j$] (j1) {};
\node [city,above of=j1] (i1) {};
\node [city,below of=S1] (k1) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip

\tikzstyle{city} = [draw, fill=white!20, circle,minimum size=1.1em, node distance=0.5cm]

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(current bounding box.center)},node distance=0.7cm]
\node [city] (S) {};
\node [coordinate,right of=S] (S1) {};
\node [city,above of=S1, label=center:$j$] (j1) {};
\node [city,above of=j1] (i1) {};
\node [city,below of=S1] (k1) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In case  the circle is too tight for the text, you can impose a slightly larger size on all circles by setting `minimum size=1.1em`, for example.

Comment: It would be better to use the `positioning` library. The `below of` syntax is deprecated.

Comment: @cfr -- Yes, but I'm not sure if the OP really needs the old syntax functionality.